# Is there any way to know if the Google Play In-App Reviews API showed the rate dialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I need to know if the rate dialog has been shown to the user. I will need to handle with another logic if it has´not been shown. Is there any way of doing that? I read almost every thread about this, but I didn't find a solution.

I read the docs and searched for alternative methods on web, but didn't find.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I will share with you my code and then explain it.

```
private var manager: ReviewManager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(activity)

/** exception will be null if userSawDialog is true. */
private lateinit var onResultListener: (success: Boolean, exception: Exception?) -> Unit

fun start() {
    val request = manager.requestReviewFlow()
    request.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val reviewInfo = task.result
            reviewInfo?.let { 
                show(reviewInfo)
            }
        } else {
            onResultListener(false, task.exception)
        }
    }
}

private fun show(reviewInfo: ReviewInfo) {
    val flow = manager.launchReviewFlow(activity, reviewInfo)
    flow.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            // Obtains if the user has seen the dialog or not, by extracting the value from the ReviewInfo object.
            // when isNoOp is false, the user has seen the dialog.
            // So, if isNoOp is false, userSawDialog will be true.
            val isNoOp = reviewInfo.toString().substring(
                reviewInfo.toString().indexOf("isNoOp") + 7,
                reviewInfo.toString().length - 1
            )
            val userSawDialog = isNoOp == "false"
            onResultListener(userSawDialog, null)
        } else {
            onResultListener(false, task.exception)
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, there is no "official" way to know whether the user saw the dialog or not. But this ReviewInfo object is in json format when transformed into a string, and then we can extract the value of the "isNoOp" field, which is false when the dialog was shown to the user, and true when it was not. Then, the variable "userSawDialog" represents whether the user saw the dialog or not. This is my code example, you should adapt it to your needs.